# Node.js encryption and browser side decryption

Tags: javascript, node.js, cross-browser, cryptography, cross-platform

I need to encrypt plain text server side (Node.js environment) and return the value back to client side. Then the browser will do the job of decryption. It should not rely on any external cryptography environment such as OpenSSL.

I read the document of node's cryptography library. It is just a wrapper of OpenSSL. I also require the client side and server side cryptography algorithm to be consistent and transparent (i.e., make use of decryption and encryption methods of the same implementation of the algorithm).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check the node-cryptojs-aes library, it provides documentation and fit into your scenario like a charm.

The url: https://github.com/chengxianga2008/node-cryptojs-aes